# Running an executable inside a "sandbox" from Java

Tags: java, process, executable

I have a java application that calls an external binary. This binary isn't very considerate of the resources it consumes and can sometimes slow my Java application down to a crawl.

Is there a way that I can predefine a resource sandbox that I can limit this binary to? Do you have any other suggestions as to how to keep this binary from interfering with my application?

Comment: Call your external library in a separate thread?  Without much, much more information about what you're trying to do, this is the best answer I can give.

Comment: It's currently being called from a separate thread. The problem is that it is a massive CPU hog, and slows down the computer significantly. Basically, I want to preassign it a share of the CPU cycles that it can use, give it its own share of memory.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a Java issue.  Can't you start the external program following a `ulimit`, at least in Unix/Linux?  I'm not sure what Windows uses;  I'm guessing it's either `start /low` or some PowerShell call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, no there isn't a way to do this.  Certainly, not in pure / portable Java.  (Java sandboxing is about managing what untrustworthy code can do, not how much resources it can use.)

In fact, I don't think there is even a reliable way to limit the CPU resources used by an external process.

The closest I can think of is trying to control thread (or process) priorities; see the [`Thread.setPriority(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority-int-) method.